# Attempting to run ts-migrate results in an error "missing script: ts-migrate"

Tags: typescript, ts-migrate

I have installed ts-migrate using the following command:
npm i ts-migrate

When that didn't work I also tried:
npm install --save-dev ts-migrate

I tried several options to run:
npm run ts-migrate
npm ts-migrate -- --help

Each time I get either Missing script: "ts-migrate"
or
Unknown command: "ts-migrate"